# How do you append environment variables to a java clojure cli?

Tags: java, clojure, clojurescript, clojure-java-interop, clojure-contrib

I have files which are created via clojure

```
frontendapp.jar
backendapp.jar
```

and take an environment variable, `APP_PORT`

What I want to understand is how do I pass variables to the jar files so that they run with the variable APP_PORT?

My assumption is something like this

```
java -jar frontenapp.jar APP_PORT=8080
```

Am I correct in my assumption?

Apologies if the question is bad, it's my first time deploying a clojure application

Comment: Not really sure what you're looking for. It'd be helpful if you could link the Java help pages that you're talking about or show us some code to understand what you've already tried. With that being said, are you aware of the `environ` Clojure library? It gives access to environment variables. See https://github.com/weavejester/environ

Comment: Hi thanks for getting in touch so quickly, I have edited the question to hopefully make it more clear

Comment: What system / shell are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a unixy shell like bash, you can do

```
$ APP_PORT=8080 java -jar frontendapp.jar
```

or perhaps more commonly:

```
$ export APP_PORT=8080
$ java -jar frontendapp.jar
```

In the first case, `APP_PORT` will only be set in the environment given to the java process. In the second case, with `export`, the variable will be set in the environments of all processes subsequently started from that shell.